# How to download an mp3 file from remote url?

Tags: php

I am redirecting my website to a url where only an mp3 file is streaming and I want that file to be downloaded to local computer.
how can i do that?

I have already searched google and stacksoverflow but the solutions didn't worked for me
I couldn't find solution for my specific problem.

Comment: can you tell us the website ?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix there you go: ***https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/soundclouduploads/APS+-+Challa+mix.mp3***

Comment: answer here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466166/force-download-mp3-with-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CURL to download, then you can use file_get_contents to save file on server, or you can use some headers to force download the file.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://url-to-file.com/audio.mp3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($status == 200) {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/audio.mp3', $output);
}
```

Download to browser:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://url-to-file.com/audio.mp3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($status == 200) {
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=audio.mp3"); 
    echo $output;
    die();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707080/download-files-from-external-url-and-pass-the-file-to-user-directly-without-sa

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh As it's a HTTPS url you need to verify host/peer.

Comment: its working but store in 0kb size what can i do same code

Answer (score 1):

`curl` only works for small files.

For larger files you can download mp3, mp4, zip by doing the following:

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/recordings/audio.mp3', fopen('http://url-to-file.com/audio.mp3', 'r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it. 
First way is use function `readfile` - it will be faster, then all other methods.

```
function curl_get_file_size( $url ) {
    $result = -1;    
    $curl = curl_init( $url );    
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    $data = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    if( $data ) {
        $content_length = "unknown";
        $status = "unknown";
        if( preg_match( "/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/", $data, $matches ) )  $status = (int)$matches[1];
        if( preg_match( "/Content-Length: (\d+)/", $data, $matches ) )   $content_length = (int)$matches[1];
        if( $status == 200 || ($status > 300 && $status <= 308) ) 
            $result = $content_length;
    }
    return $result;
}

function run() {
        global $url,$title;
        header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title.mp3");
        header("Content-length: " . curl_get_file_size($url));
        header("accept-ranges: bytes");
        readfile($url);
    }
run();
```

Second way is when you download full file and then return it

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($status == 200) {
    header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title.mp3");
    header("Content-length: " . strlen($output));
    header("accept-ranges: bytes");
    echo $output;
    die();
}
```