# Convert a file into string, import those strings to 3rd party downloader and download the file

Tags: php, string, download

I want to download a file in such way. 1st i need to open the file as string in such way.

download.php

```
 $dstring = file_get_contents('http://domain/file/song.mp3');
    echo $dstring;
```

[image]

Then i need a app that can read those script that will automatically regenerate the file and download it by putting the URL as

```
mydomain/download.php?link=domain/file/song.mp3
```

Please Note that i am not allowed to regenerate those string using php.  is there any way to do this or any app that can download file in this way?

Comment: Why can't you use cUrl like in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856193/how-to-download-an-mp3-file-from-remote-url ?