# How can I force downloads from external host?

Tags: php, curl, mp3, external, force-download

How can I force a download from an external host? It had been working by default on desktop and mobile but recently stopped working on mobile. Forcing it via `.htaccess` file does not work.

I searched and found two possible solutions - one is by using CURL and the other PHP. I'm leaning towards PHP. These two solutions are located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/531292) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37856193)

Using the PHP method I created this file:

```
$file_name = 'file.mp3';
  $file_url = 'https://partyfavorz.podbean.com/' . $file_name;
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
  readfile($file_url);
  exit;
```

I named it `download.php`. However, I do not know where to place this file. I uploaded it to the `public_html` folder but that had no effect.

Comment: Is this _"download"_ as meaning play inside an `<audio>` tag or download to disk (save file)?

Comment: Download to disk (save file). It works on desktop but no longer in mobile. It's coming from an external source Podbean who just replied and said it's not on their end. Could it be my CDN?